# Objective c: NSDateFormatter with region format without year

Tags: objective-c

I used this code to get region date format.

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
[formatter setDateStyle: NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSString * getFormate = [formatter dateFormat];
NSLog(@"getFormate  = %@",getFormate );
```

When i change region to other country, the result are:

- US :  getFormate: EEEE, MMMM d, y
- Japanese: getFormate: y年M月d日EEEE
- Thai: getFormate: EEEEที่ d MMMM G y

But what i want to get are

- US :  getFormate: EEEE, MMMM d
- Japanese: getFormate: M月d日EEEE
- Thai: getFormate: EEEEที่ d MMMM G

I want to remove year from these format.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you replace `y` from the string with empty string?

Comment: If i replace y with empty string, it correct for US format. But for   Japanese, Korean and other countries are still incorrect. For example: Japanese format need to remove "y年" not only "y"

Comment: Put your date format strings in your translation file and use NSLocalizedString to pick the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [+dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDateFormatter/dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale)

For the date components you want it will try its best to give you the date format string for the locale you provide.

In your case you probably want to pass: "EEEEMMMMd".

See the example in the documentation I linked to for a concrete example.

---

Edit : Just in case you don't want to go through the apple docs

```
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
NSLocale *gbLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];

NSString *dateFormat;
NSString *dateComponents = @"yMMMMd";

dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:dateComponents options:0 locale:usLocale];
NSLog(@"Date format for %@: %@",
    [usLocale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:[usLocale localeIdentifier]], dateFormat);

dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:dateComponents options:0 locale:gbLocale];
NSLog(@"Date format for %@: %@",
    [gbLocale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:[gbLocale localeIdentifier]], dateFormat);

// Output:
// Date format for English (United States): MMMM d, y
// Date format for English (United Kingdom): d MMMM y
```

Comment: @MartinR pfandare didn't copied it, I edited the answer and the code is taken from the apple docs as linked by pfandare. IMHO there is no need of attribution

Comment: Thanks Inder Kumar Rathore, your answer is correct.
Have a nice day.